# Visual Studio/Visual Basic 2010 Smartsheet & API

Tags: visual-studio-2010, smartsheet-api

I am developing an application that is using smartsheet as the database tables, with a visual studio 2010/visual basic off line app to make a report (purchase order).

The smartsheet odbc is not working great and i need to put data back to smartsheet at the end of the process.

Ideally i am looking to avoid going to C# for this project as i have never done coding in this language.

Smartsheet does support https api, but i am not sure if this will actually work?

Answer (score 0):

The Smartsheet ODBC driver is READ ONLY and doesn't support sending updates back to your sheets. It will only pull data out from Smartsheet.
The [Smartsheet API](https://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/) is your best bet to work with the data in your sheets to pull data from them and update the data as well.
There is a [C# SDK](https://github.com/smartsheet-platform/smartsheet-csharp-sdk) to help make working with the Smartsheet API easier.
There are also sample apps for both [C#](https://github.com/smartsheet-samples/csharp-read-write-sheet) and [VB.net](https://github.com/smartsheet-samples/vb-read-write-sheet) that how to get started interacting with the Smartsheet API.

Comment: Thanks Dave.  I could not find the VB.net versions and have had issues opening the C# versions on Visual Studio 2010.  Can you provide links to the vb.net?

Comment: The VB.net example I linked to above still uses the same C# SDK, but in Visual Basic. As it notes in the Details section of the README "Since all .net languages are interoperable, we can use the C# SDK from Visual Basic. To add a reference to the SDK, right-click the project in Solution Explorer and pick Manage NuGet Packages. Browse for 'smartsheet' to add a reference to the smartsheet-csharp-sdk."